# What do you call this approach on ASP.net Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET Core MVC , and I'm watching a lot of courses and tutorials about it but the current project that I'm working with, is a little different from what I have learned through tutotials and courses.

On my project solution I have a folder containing classes.

And on that classes contains Entity Class,Constructor,Factory Methods,CriteriaInfo Class and Data Access and also each class extends into an Assemblies.

Is this approach is MVC but using a class library ? Because the model I think is in the class because I'm not seeing any model on my Model folder(except for the defaults).

Comment: It would be useful if we could see some code snippets around this. In essence though, it doesn’t matter what the project type is to be classed as mvc. Mvc is just the separation of concerns where the view is what is being displayed to the user, the controller is the business logic and the model is the data around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

if you are using visual studio then it will  create a default mvc project on users request, and there will probably no folders  for models, if you want you can put these models to a folder or into another project as a class library. All these changes are upto the developer concern.

Class library is nothing but just a another namesapce, where we can save the files and can be use to multiple project if the dev wants to

you can find the type class library when you search in studio

[image]

the only thing is to select the appropriate type for your project. It will gives you the basic template just like you created the mvc project. you can edit upon the template

official documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

good tutorial
https://dotnettutorials.net/course/asp-net-core-tutorials/